# Magento<->Wordpress Sharing Session ID / Headers already sent

Tags: php, wordpress, magento, session, cookies

I'm loading the Magento header into a Wordpress site (on the same domain).  Currently have this in a Wordpress header.php to pull in the Magento header:

```
    require_once "shop/app/Mage.php";
    umask(0);
    Mage::app('default');

    Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));

    $layout = Mage::app()->getLayout();
    $layout->getUpdate()
        ->addHandle('default')
        ->load();

    $layout->generateXml()
           ->generateBlocks();

    $header = $layout->getBlock('header')->toHtml();
    echo $header;
```

It works, but it doesn't pull in the correct products / number of items in the cart.  This is because when you hit the Wordpress site it sets a session ID, and then when you hit /shop it sets another one.  I've tried to set the cookie path in Magento to / rather than /shop but then I get a conflict where the Wordpress homepage says:

```
Cannot send headers; headers already sent
```

How do I share the session ID between Magento and Wordpress - either by fixing the cookie path issue or another way?  I've tried **everything** I can find on Stack Overflow and nothing seems to work....

Answer (score 0):

So I solved this using the information in this link:

http://developer.blueearth.net/2011/11/16/magento-wordpress-integration-part-1/

The author states that:

> Don’t Send Headers Twice
>
> Next we need to stop Magento from sending headers after they’ve already been sent by WordPress. This could occur in more places later, but so far I’ve only encountered the problem on login. This time we need to copy the App.php file from ~/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php to ~/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/App.php. Find the function “getResponse()” (At line 1221 for Magento version 1.6.1.0) and comment out the following line:

```
$this->_response->setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```

This prevents Magento sending the header when you are in the Wordpress site (which is able to send the header first because of the way the two are linked together).  I don't know if this is the ideal solution but it works, and I'm able to share cart information between Wordpress and Magento now.  I've also updated my original post to reflect the tidier code that I went with in the end.